# Wpf control size to content?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, autosize

How do I make a WPF control to change its size according the content in it?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

For most controls, you set its height and width to `Auto` in the XAML, and it will size to fit its content.

In code, you set the width/height to `double.NaN`.  For details, see [FrameworkElement.Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx), particularly the "remarks" section.

Comment: In addition a lot of controls set their Horizontal- and VerticalAlignment to Stretch which will cause them to fill an available area so you will probably need to specify these properties, e.g. HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top".

Answer (score 37):

I had a problem like this whereby I had specified the width of my Window, but had the height set to `Auto`.  The child `DockPanel` had it's `VerticalAlignment` set to Top and the Window had it's VerticalContentAlignment set to Top, yet the Window would still be much taller than the contents.

Using Snoop, I discovered that the `ContentPresenter` within the Window (part of the Window, not something I had put there) has it's `VerticalAlignment` set to `Stretch` and can't be changed without retemplating the entire Window!

After a lot of frustration, I discovered the `SizeToContent` property - you can use this to specify whether you want the Window to size vertically, horizontally or both, according to the size of the contents - everything is sizing nicely now, I just can't believe it took me so long to find that property!

Comment: When the problem applies to the top level window Set SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight". I lost hours on this one - it's not intuitive! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812079/window-heightauto-problem

Comment: Although a `Window` is a `Control`, I think the OP was referring to a `UserControl`, which doesn't have a `SizeToContent ` property. Otherwise the OP would use the term "Window" in the subject.

Answer (score 3):

I had a user control which sat on page in a free form way, not constrained by another container,  and the contents within the user control would not auto size but expand to the full size of what the user control was handed.

To get the user control to simply size to its content, for height only, I placed it into a grid with on row set to auto size such as this:

```
<Grid Margin="0,60,10,200">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <controls1:HelpPanel x:Name="HelpInfoPanel"
                         Visibility="Visible"
                         Width="570"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding HelpItems}"
                         Background="#FF313131" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the grid or alike component:
In XAML, make sure that the elements in the grid have Grid.Row and Grid.Column defined, and ensure tha they don't have margins. If you used designer mode, or Expression Blend, it could have assigned margins relative to the whole grid instead of to particular cells.
As for cell sizing, I add an extra cell that fills up the rest of the space:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```