# How to get WPF usercontrol designheight and designwidth at run time

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I need to access a WPF usercontrol's designheight and designwidth at runtime.  I know this is impossible, so I'll explain why I want to do it, and hopefully someone can provide an example of the right approach.

From a C# winforms app, I open a new window containing a very large WPF usercontrol.  If the monitor I'm running on can handle it, I want it to open the window at the full design size of the usercontrol.  If the monitor I'm running on can't handle it, then I want to open the window as large as possible, leaving 1 pixel on each side of the screen.  So I need to know the usercontrol's current design width and height before the usercontrol is displayed.

I want to avoid hard coding values in the winforms app, or using unbound public properties in the user control, because then I have to trust other developers to update them when they change the user control. I don't know if it's possible to bind a local variable to designheight or designwidth, or how to code that in XAML.  Since I don't know a lot of WPF, there may be some other way to reach the goal that I don't know about.

Thanks for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like [Resize WPF Window and contents depening on screen resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121906/resize-wpf-window-and-contents-depening-on-screen-resolution)

The answer suggests that you bind the screen size to the window height and width. It will automatically size the window according to screen size. You can even set a % value for the size of the window.

Comment: Thanks but this could result in displaying the usercontrol larger than its designheight and designwidth.