# What screen size to use?

Tags: c#, screen, tablet

So, I am developing an app for tablets in C#, WPF. I do not have one to test on it, but the customer told me the screen is 10-17 inches big.

I am wondering what screen size to test my app.
I am using the grid for layout, but when I say for example
GridRow1.height=2*
GridRow2.height=3*
It does not look the same on full screen and on smaller window sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience screen resolution would be more of a factor in usability.

See here for a solution:

- [resize-wpf-window-and-contents-depening-on-screen-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121906/resize-wpf-window-and-contents-depening-on-screen-resolution)

The TL;DR

```
<Window x:Class="YourApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="YourApplication" 
    Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" 
    Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}">
```