# How do I get stackpanel to resize to fit the controls it's stacking?

Tags: wpf, stackpanel

I'm making a toolbar.  I want the width of the window to equal the total width of the buttons.  StackPanel seems perfect for the job because it lines everything up, but it won't stretch.

```
  <Window Width="auto">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="auto">
        <Button />
        <Button />
     </StackPanel>
  </Window>
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a very simple solution! Almost everybody (I've been searching tons of pages) suggests switching control types or something much more complex, but in fact, it's much simpler:

```
<Window         SizeToContent="Width"
```

That's the only change required.

The source of this bit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2317914/971583, the second-ranked answer to the problem, which seems to me the better one.

Comment: However, this reply is not stretching your buttons:)

Comment: Who said anything about stretching buttons.  I want the container to resize.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the width of the window to equal the total width of the buttons using a UniformGrid instead of a StackPanel.

```
<UniformGrid Margin="10" Rows="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="No" FontSize="18" Margin="5" Padding="6,3"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Yes, Absolutely" Margin="5" Padding="6,3"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Maybe" Margin="5" Padding="6,3"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

The UniformGrid provides eacg cell is the same height and the same width.  This is what you want as you then avoid having to set the button sizes manually.

**Update:**

I would suggest not to use Stackpanel. Even if you make the Stackpanel fill its parent, its children still "stacks" and won't fill the Stackpanel.

Comment: re, edit: I'm not trying to get StackPanel to fill the parent.  I'm trying to get the parent to grow/shrink to fit the StackPanel.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu and you've found it?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your setting, you can achieve that simply using StackPanel's alignments. For example this XAML

```
<Window Width="350" Height="350" ...> 
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel
            Background="Green">
            <Border
                Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Background="Blue" />
            <Border
                Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Background="Red" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Will create this (the panel stretches to parent's size):

[image]

And this panel:

```
<Window Width="350" Height="350" ...> 
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Background="Green">
            <Border
                Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Background="Blue" />
            <Border
                Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Background="Red" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Will create this (sized to the two contained Borders):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a Grid with Columns instead.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" />
    <Button Grid.Column="2" />
    <Button Grid.Column="3" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't like grid, because I have to put in all these column definitions.  If I add more controls, I need to update all the column numbers.  It seems to me that Grid is useful when you have a rectangle with multiple rows of controls.  A single row doesn't seem to make sense.